# Ideal Currency In Terms Of Coin Values

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, recreational-mathematics

Assume we have some currency where $n$ is the value of the smallest bill and all the coins have a value in $C\subseteq[n]:=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.  Assume further that for each $a\in\mathbf{N}$ there is a unique decomposition into a minimal amount of coins, so e.g. not $1,2,3,4\in C$.

Now assume that the change I receive from a shop always assumes this smallest decomposition, e.g. I'd never receive 57 single pennies in the US or cents in the EU.  I ignore bill transactions and assume modulo $n$ arithmetic, i.e. I have to pay the price $a \in [n]:=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, for which I can pay any amount $b\in [n]$ in any coin configuration and receive $b-a$ if $b\ge a$ and $n+b-a$ else.

In an alternative formulation of the problem I can pay any amount I want (even larger than $n$) but then the question is, if $n=100$, $a=1$ and $b=500$, do I get $499$ or $99$ back?  It seems to make the math more complicated in any way.

So a coin selection strategy is a map from multisets $m_C$ over $C$ and $a\in [n]$ to submultisets of $m_C$, i.e. I can only select coins which are already in my wallet.  If $a$ in uniquely distributed in $[n]$ then for every fixed coin selection strategy I get a Markov chain where the nodes are multisets over $C$ (or wallet configurations).

My questions:

- Can I always limit my reachable wallet configurations to a finite set if I choose the right strategy (e.g. never having more than 100 coins)?
- If this is the case, what strategy minimizes the expected amount of coins in my wallet in the limit when I start with $0$ coins?
- Is there a case where selecting a greedy strategy minimizing the amount of coins after each transaction does not yield the best overall strategy?
- For fixed $n$, how should $C$ look like to minimize the expected amount of coins in the wallet under the optimal coin selection strategy?

Comment: If $n=100$ can you pay with two 60 cent coins?

Comment: Good question.  Yeah, I think that should be allowed.  I'll reformulate my question, although I suspect it makes the math more complicated...

Comment: [Related, but less specific, question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200775/how-to-divide-currency/)

Comment: If you can pay whatever you want, but change is $\mod n$, then you can definitely always have finite coins by giving all of yours away